# Looking for a simple approach for handling user $_POST data without AJAX?

Tags: forms

I'm looking for a simple way for a Wordpress plugin to process `$_POST` data from a **user** submitted form.  Back end processing will be performed and then I'll redirect to a new page as appropriate — so during processing there is no UI.

Basically, I want to take a form submit such as...

```
   <form method="post" action="/back-end-processing.php">
     <input type="text" name="text" />
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>';
```

...and process it like I would with PHP but still be able to use WP's "nonce" protection.

Some examples I've seen suggest that I should use `admin-post.php` but I was concerned that it should only be used for actual **admins** and not for general **users**.

Another approach suggested...

```
function checkCheckBox()
{
    if($_POST['checkbox'] == 1)
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}

add_action('init', 'checkCheckBox');
```

...however, this seems like overkill because it will be called for every page while my site visitors will only be posting data to it infrequently.

Comment: why is that a overkill? it's a simple conditional check to see if a variable has a certain value... you can hook 456539436 of those to `init` and you still wouldn't be able to sense any performance hits...

Answer (score 2):

The best way to process the custom form is the following. If you are using nonce then you don't really have to check $_POST['checkbox'], the code below can be used simply to verify_nonce and then process the form.

```
function process_my_form() {
    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_nonce_field'], 'my_nonce' ) ) {
        // process your form here
        // you can also redirect and call exit here.
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'process_my_form' );
```

But if you still you want to submit your form to a custom php script, then load the wp-blog-header.php.

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website`.  As with most things PHP, there are many ways to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Settings API, and process the `$_POST` data inside the validation callback function?

EDIT:

Oh, wait: you said *front-end* form, which I assume is not related to Plugin options? (If the form *does* for some reason update Plugin options, [see here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/save-theme-options-options-php-from-the-frontend).)

How are you adding your form? Shortcode? Post data? Hard-coded into the template?